# Why is my custom Validator for inner object not used to validate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I have a custom Validator which looks like this:

```
@Component
public class PersonFormValidator implements Validator {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.myapp.generator.component.impl.PersonFormValidator.class);

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Contractor.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Contractor contractor = (Contractor) target;
        if (contractor.getContractorData().getNip() == null || contractor.getContractorData().getNip().equals("")) {
            errors.rejectValue("contractorData.nip", "empty");
        }
        logger.error(errors.toString());
    }
}
```

On the Thymeleaf template side it is looking like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/contractor/update/{id}(id=${contractor.id})}" th:object="${contractor}" method="post">
        <ul class="form-style-1">
<li>
     <label>NIP<span class="required">*</span></label>
     <input type="text" th:field="*{contractorData.nip}" id="nip" th:value="${contractor.contractorData?.nip}" >
     <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('contractorData.nip')}" th:errors="*{contractorData.nip}">Generic error</span>
</li>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contractor/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String updateContractor(@PathVariable("id") String id, @Validated @ModelAttribute("contractor") Contractor contractor, Model model, BindingResult result) {
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    logger.error("BINDING RESULT ERROR");
    return "index";
} else {
    Contractor contractorPO = contractorRepository.findById(id).get();
    ContractorData contractorData = 
    //not important code here
    contractorPO.setContractorData(contractorData);
    contractorRepository.save(contractorPO);
    model.addAttribute("contractor", contractorPO);
    return "index";
}
```

And of course I have the validator registered:

```
@InitBinder({"invoicedata", "contractor"})
protected void initPersonFormBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(invoiceFormValidator, personFormValidator);
}
```

When I start the app and go to the app address, I get an error like this:

> Invalid target for Validator
>   [com.myapp.generator.component.impl.InvoiceFormValidator@e52be6c]:
>   Contractor(id=5cc193e581c7dc75cfb7bcff, email=some@mail.com,
>   contractorData=ContractorData(firstName=Name, lastName=Lastname,
>   businessName=Apple, businessLocation=Warsaw, nip=,
>   regon=adgadgdagdag), invoices=[])

Nothing is working for me, I am fighting with this problem since yesterday...

What can I change in my code to make the validation work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that both validators are applied to both forms:

- For invoiceData; apply invoiceFormValidator AND personFormValidator
- For contractor; apply invoiceFormValidator AND personFormValidator

What if you'd bind the validators in two separate methods?

```
@InitBinder("invoicedata")
protected void invoiceDataBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(invoiceFormValidator);
}

@InitBinder("contractor")
protected void contractorDataBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(personFormValidator);
}
```

Comment: That helped me, but I have another problem now :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55850511/one-validator-redirecting-correctly-another-one-not-redirecting-at-all