# One validator redirecting correctly, another one not redirecting at all?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I have two Validators registered in my Controller. The problem is - InvoiceFormValidator works perfectly, returns errors when there are any, and redirects to desired page, with the form filled out with data.

The second one is not redirecting at all, it is just redirecting me to my error page, showing me:

> Date  Thu Apr 25 15:22:57 CEST 2019 Path
>     /contractor/update/5cc193e581c7dc75cfb7bcff Error   Bad Request Status
>     400 Message     Validation failed for object='contractor'. Error count:
>   1

Now the code: (I'm presenting just the important part of the code)

```
@Autowired private InvoiceFormValidator invoiceFormValidator;
@Autowired private PersonFormValidator personFormValidator;

@InitBinder({"invoicedata"})
protected void initPersonFormBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(invoiceFormValidator);
}

@InitBinder({"contractor"})
protected void initContractorFormBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(personFormValidator);
}
```

This is how it looks on the controller side (for `initPersonFormBinder`:)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addinvoice", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String addInvoice(@CurrentUser Contractor contractor, @ModelAttribute("invoicedata") @Validated InvoiceData invoicedata, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add";
        } else {
```

And for `initContractorFormBinder`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contractor/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String updateContractor(@PathVariable("id") String id, @ModelAttribute("contractor") @Validated Contractor contractor, Model model, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr)  {
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    logger.error("BINDING RESULT ERROR");
    return "index";
} else {
```

The problem here is that the code never enters this method, NEVER reaches the `if` statement.

Now the code side of InvoiceFormValidator:

```
@Component
public class InvoiceFormValidator implements Validator {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InvoiceFormValidator.class);

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return InvoiceData.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "receptionDate", "empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "orderDate", "empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "invoiceIssueDate", "empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "contractDate", "empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "invoiceNumber", "empty");
    }
}
```

And the same time, PersonFormValidator looks like this:

```
@Component
public class PersonFormValidator implements Validator {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.look4app.generator.component.impl.PersonFormValidator.class);

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Contractor.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Contractor contractor = (Contractor) target;
        if (contractor.getContractorData().getNip() == null || contractor.getContractorData().getNip().equals("")) {
            errors.rejectValue("contractorData.nip", "empty");
        }
        logger.error("CONTRACTOR VALIDATION ERROR");
    }
}
```

And a small part of the Thymeleaf template here, for the part which is not working:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/contractor/update/{id}(id=${contractor.id})}" th:object="${contractor}" method="post">
            <ul class="form-style-1">
                <li>
                    <label>NIP<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{contractorData.nip}" id="nip" th:value="${contractor.contractorData?.nip}" >
                    <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('contractorData.nip')}" th:errors="*{contractorData.nip}">Generic error</span>
                </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Zapisz dane firmy" />
            </li>
```

Same HTML for the WORKING validation is a bit different, but not that much:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{addinvoice}" th:object="${invoicedata}" method="post">
            <ul class="form-style-1">

                <li>
                    <label>Komentarz</label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{contractorComment}" id="contractorComment">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Zapisz protokół" />
                </li>
```

What is wrong with this redirecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the subtle difference in the order of the method parameters:

```
public String addInvoice      (... @ModelAttribute("invoicedata") @Validated InvoiceData invoicedata, BindingResult result, Model model, ...) {
public String updateContractor(... @ModelAttribute("contractor")  @Validated Contractor contractor, Model model, BindingResult result, ...)  {
```

The `BindingResult` parameter should come right after the parameter with the `@Validated`. If you change your method signature to:

```
public String updateContractor(@PathVariable("id") String id, @ModelAttribute("contractor") @Validated Contractor contractor, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes attr)  {
```

You should be able to access your method. If a `BindingResult` parameter is present *directly after* the `@ModelAttribute`, Spring puts the validation result in the `BindingResult` and calls the method, where you can process the `BindingResult` manually. Otherwise, Spring handles the validation and skips the method.

Comment: Oh my god, that is the SECOND time I am failing on the same thing :D Thanks, it works now :D